# How to restore pre-windows-8 Alt+Shift keyboard behavior?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, input-languages

Before Windows 8, the `Alt+Shift` shortcut changed the input method (keyboard layout) for the current app. This permitted to map an input method to each app.

For example I could keep the default layout for my apps where I write in english and switch to a french layout in apps where I write in french. This was working great: each app had his keyboard layout.

Now with Windows 8 the Alt+Shift key has a global behavior for all applications. This meens I have to change my input method almost each time I change from app to app.

Is there a way to restore the pre-Windows-8 behavior?
Or is there another shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a new "advanced language settings" panel.

[image]

Use the "Let me set a different input method for each app window" to check.